# how to get "int" value result in json as "string" using metamug

Tags: json, metamug

for example: I'm getting `[{"id":100}]`

while i require: `[{"id":"100"}]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the integer value in the form of a string. To convert the integer to a string you can use the CONCAT() function.

Something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.1">
    <Request method="GET">
        <Query> 
           select CONCAT('',100) as 'id'
        </Query>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

The resulting json will have value in form of a string.

```
[{"id": "100"}]
```

Alternatively using CAST() function will also yield the same result.

```
    <Query> 
        select CAST(100 as char(5)) as 'value'
    </Query>
```